GetInputHtml and conditionals
I have my own plugin that uses ajax to get the fields, (in this instance an entry type), I get the html, and the js and insert it into the page. This works, the js works on all fields so far. Everything works, except conditionals in entry types. So the fields in the entry type works, but the if/else on select field that should make my input fields show/hide, does not work. Of course on reload when it renders normally this also works, so it seems the ajax call is missing the conditional js from the rest of the js?
